# How to sync local files with head revision?

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo XYZ and a folder ABC where all the repo´s current files are in.

I would like to tell git locally that this folder ABC is linked to the repo XYZ and that all the files that are present are the actual latest revision.

So that I can pull new changes or commit changes to the repo properly.

Comment: If you downloaded a .zip archive, you have nothing that looks like a git repository. You need the history. Try a shallow clone.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I don´t have the internet capacity to do a clone, or even a shallow clone. See the comment below to the first answer please.

Comment: Every commit in git builds on the previous commits; if you change one commit anywhere in the history, it affects all subsequent commits. Unless you do a shallow clone (of at least one commit), you *can not* do what you're asking. Period.

Answer (score 0):

First, clone the github repo into a new, empty directory.

Then, using standard OS methods (`cp` in Linux, drag&drop in Windows, or whichever way you prefer), copy your local files over the cloned files.

From here on, simply `git add` the actually changed files, `git commit`, `git push` as usual. You can now delete your previous local directory (the non-git one) and keep working with the gitified one.

Comment: I don´t think the part got through where I have an 800MB repo that I cannot clone, pull or push through git. I have the files on my harddrive. I want to be able to set the local folder to be the latest revision without commit - so if I add and commit something it will only be changes from here onwards. And if I pull it will tell me that I´m at the latest revision.That´s what I want.

Comment: Is the local folder a git repository in itself (is there a `.git` directory inside it) or not?